# in javascript, what happens if: x = []; x.push(x);?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

```
var x = []; 
x.push(x);
```

`x` now seems to be an infinitely deep russian-doll type meta array.

if you check `x[0][0][0]`.... as many `[0]` indexes as you add, it still returns a one-item array.

but is there a finite depth cutoff? or are new levels procedurally generated when you check? those are the only two possibilities I can think of.

Comment: *" are new levels procedurally generated when you check"* No, you simply add a reference to itself. There are no "levels". You have the same in browser with `window.self`: `window.self === window`. So you can do `window.self.self.self` or `window.window.window.window`. It's the shortest form a *circular reference*.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. the variable name x is a reference to the memory location, but there can be any number of duplicate references to the same object. I guess I was confused because I usually think of arrays and objects as branching tree structures of containment, but of course they don't have to obey those structural constraints. Good to break that habit of thought.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense to think of them like trees. In this case, it would be more of a general graph though with one node that has a self loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var x = []; 
x.push(x);
```

> x now seems to be an infinitely deep russian-doll type meta array.

Not really.  `x` is an array.  The first element in the array points to the same memory location as `x` itself.  Nothing more, nothing less.

But yes, you can do

```
x[0][0][0]
```

as many times as you like, since you're just re-referencing the same memory location over and over again.

Comment: @Prasanth - I'm not sure what else there is to say.

Comment: First thing I tried on x was JSON.stringify, and returned an error. I never knew circular structures existed.. do you know any practical use of these?

Comment: @Prasanth I can't off the top of my head think of a useful use case for an array that contained itself, but one may very well exist.

Comment: @Prasanth: I wouldn't say there is a "practical use" for them, they are rather a consequence of being able to traverse something in two directions. E.g.  DOM nodes have a `children` property, allowing you to traverse down, but also a `parentNode` property, allowing you to traverse up. That creates a circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is generated when you get the x at any level. The x is inserted as a reference.

When dereferencing x[0], you get x.

x == x[0];

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop here.  You are creating an empty array and setting it into `x`.  Then the next line `x.push(x);` is just pushing an empty array in to `x`.  If you where to add do `x.push(x);` again it would push an array into `x` that has an empty array in the first index.

Comment: I think you accidentally double posted.  You might want to delete one of your answers and just edit the other as desired.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that and deleted the doubled post.  At least I thought I did, are you still seeing 2 from me?

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for the heads up though.